# split some data inside html table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I have code to populate the cell of table by:

``````````````````````
{% for row in data %}
`````````````````````
<td> {{ row[4] }}</td>
`````````````````````
``````````````````````

Now, I have the data "['sugar']:['3642847']:['2020-08-21']". I wanted to write "sugar" instead of all the string.

Now, I have written the code as just to split. I might have mixed up javascript with html there, which I could do best.

```````````````````````
{% for row in data %}
   <tr>
   ``````````````````````
   <td> <script>var str1={{row[4]}}.split(:)[0];document.write(str1);</script></td>
```````````````````````

This doesn't work....I am quite beginner.

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: `split(":")` You need quotation marks here as well. (And the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` should have given you a hint).

Comment: it still doesn't fix it, it shows though "Unexpected token '&'", but theres no '&' (inspect shows "var str1=[&#39;sugar"

Comment: `var str1="{{row[4]}}".split(':')[0];document.write(str1);`  More missing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript to this string operation is bad practice (actually worst practice). You can do all of that in twig like so: [(twig fiddle here)](https://twigfiddle.com/aq9dne)

```
{% set myString = "['sugar']:['3642847']:['2020-08-21']" %}
{{ myString|split(']:[').0|replace({'[':'', "'":''}) }}
{# outputs: sugar #}
```

as I understood your question this might be all you need

```
{{ row[4]|split(']:[').0|replace({'[':'', "'":''}) }}
```

Comment: Can you please cross check the last one solution you have provided? it was giving an error, sorry don't have the data to test right now, actually, i dont know how to do that on dummy data

Comment: @arnabdasgupta what error did you get? from your question you say `{{ row[4] }}` has the the string `['sugar']:['3642847']:['2020-08-21']` on which the code works. if you have another string post the correct value please